# Why does the URL changes to the action name to which I have posted the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, razor

I have this Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        //[Bind("")]
        public ActionResult AddStories(Stories st, HttpPostedFileBase files)
        {
            try
            {
                if (files != null)
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/"), Path.GetFileName(files.FileName));
                    files.SaveAs(filePath);
                }

                st.Image = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                listofStories.Clear();
                listofStories = bo.GetAllImages();

                if (bo.insertImages(st))
                {
                    ViewBag.Data = "Added";

                    ViewBag.Grid = listofStories;

                    ViewBag.Style = "display:none";
                    ViewBag.StyleAdd = "";
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Data = ex.Message;
            }


            return View("GetStories", st);
        }
```

and for it, I have a bound partial view which is embedded inside the main view, **GetStories**.

When I submit data to it then the URL changes to /Stories/AddStories but I want it to be of parent's view such as /Stories/GetStories, after posting the data to AddStories.

I tried several things but nothing works.

I am naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post, your browser navigates to the post url. There are only two ways to have it show a different url afterwards:

- instead of returning the view *as though* they had hit that url, return a *redirect* to the preferred url (so the browser does a post followed by a get)
- use client-side trickery to change the displayed url - for example  [`replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)
  (browser dependent)

When you posted this question, for example, your browser did a POST to `/questions/ask/submit`, and the last line of the C# behind that route was a redirect to `/questions/46975286/why-does-the-url-changes-to-the-action-name-to-which-i-have-posted-the-data`

Comment: @StackyUnderflow for the record, another advantage of the post/redirect/get approach is that it avoids the "refreshing the page will resubmit your content" warning that most browsers do. Refreshing a "get" is meant to be fine ("get" is meant to be idempotent)

Comment: yeah that's true. I guess that's what AJAX does too.

Comment: but I guess, Post does throw that warning, bcz till now i was using post and was facing tht resubmission warning